# LNA RF preamplifier for DC-30Mhz

Tags: amplifier, rf

Could anyone suggest what's the best way to design DC-30Mhz LNA, any references?

My goal is to have ~10-15dB amplification with as low as possible noise. Both transistor based and IC-based variants are considered.

I've seen that MMIC's for higher frequencies have noise figure down to 0.7-1dB, but none of these LNA's could work below 50-100Mhz. MMIC's which can work down to DC magically have noise figure of 3-4dB.

Is it possible to achieve such low noise at low frequencies?

Ideally this amplifier will be before RTLSDR+Up Converter and narrow bandpass filter.

Comment: That's well within the frequencies where you can consider commodity op-amps. There should be lots of options.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I see, thanks. But what about noise figure? Noise for opamps is specified in nV/sqrt(Hz), and I don't see if they are close or not to theoretical "low-noise limit". I could imagine that feedback resistors introduce quite a bit of extra noise compared to MMIC LNA. Also, integral MMIC's are often use GaAs/SiGe technology and I wonder if that offer any benefits for lowering the noise.

Comment: Can you explain more about the last sentence in your question specifically what does ideally mean and what is RTLSDR?

Comment: @Andy aka [RTL-SDR](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr) is a software-defined radio system which (ab)uses Realtek TV card's ability to output direct I/Q samples from its ADC. Problem with it is that the cards are usually not suitable for work with low frequencies so various methods are used to move interesting frequencies up in spectrum so that they are in tuneable range of the card.

Comment: Designing an LNA from scratch is a rather serious effort. What noise figure are you really trying to achieve? Can your bands be divided? does it need to be one LNA or can you have different bands?

Comment: You could see the Alphalab LNA 10 for USD $385, but the configurable low-pass filter (single pole) runs from 1Hz-1MHz, and if set to AC coupled then there is also a 0.3Hz high-pass (single pole) filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texas instruments have a good article on how to calculate Noise Figure for op-amps. [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt094/slyt094.pdf) is the document and below is a summary of what they find for the THS3202 op-amp: -

[image]

They recommend using a spreadsheet and all the formulas are in the document.

Comment: Thanks for nice document. But as far as I see - noise figure is huge: ~13dB compared to 1-3dB for MMIC's. So I guess opamps are just too noisy for that.

Answer (score 0):

I often look to minicircuits.com for gear like this; not for any particular reason other than the fact that their stuff is popular in the Amateur Radio community. Here's a list of some of their amplifiers that look decent: http://www.minicircuits.com/products/amplifiers_smt_high_dyr_range.shtml

You're still looking at a NF of 2.7dB though, although with 21dB of gain. I looked around a bunch and couldn't find anything cleaner than that...

Comment: A bit more research suggests that the HF bands are pretty noisy as it is and having a low NF isn't a huge advantage. Maybe that's why it's tough to find someone who makes a super low NF amplifier for HF?

Comment: It's not that the HF bands are noisy, it's that a low NF is tougher to achieve. In fact, even an extra 0.1 dB better NF at higher bands can be the difference between your LNA being chosen (when you're the one trying to sell them).